# How can I navigate to another route from actions in Vue's Pinia store?

Tags: javascript, vue-router, vuejs3, pinia

I'm currently working in a Vue 3 project.

Using the `this.$router.push({})` doesn't seem to work in the Pinia store.

I have also tried importing the useRouter --> `import { useRouter } from "vue-router";` to simply use router.push, but yet nothing still seems to work.

I don't know what could be the problem or what I should use to navigate my routes from the actions in the Pinia store.

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";

export const SignupStore = defineStore("signup", {
  state: () => ({
    fullName: "",
    dob: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    passwordConfirm: "",
    gender: "",
    program: "",
    genderOptions: ["Male", "Female"],
    degreePrograms: ["Degree program", "HND program", "Masters program"],
    isSignupCorrect: false,
  }),

  actions: {
    async signup() {
      let dob = new Date(this.dob).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
      let gender = this.gender.substring(0, 1);
      let program = this.program;
      if (program == "Degree program") {
        program = "De";
      } else if (program == "HND program") {
        program = "Hn";
      } else {
        program = "Ms";
      }

      console.log(dob);
      console.log(program);

      await axios
        .post("register/", {
          full_name: this.fullName,
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
          gender: gender,
          dob: dob,
          program: program,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('response status is ' + response.status)
            if (response.status == 201) {
                router.push({ name: "AdmissionDashboard" });
              }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response) {
            console.log("signup error traced");
          }
        });
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: You need to import YOUR router, rather than the Vue instance. For example, `import router from '@/router';` where `./src/router.js` implements Vue's router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only place that you need to import `vue-router` is in your router file.

You can then use it anywhere in the app, by importing YOUR router file (which implrments vue-router).

So all you need to do in your store, is import your router, then call the push method, like you're doing, and it should work.

Comment: I'm working in a vue 3 project of which I already made this import in my router.js file << import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router" >>

Comment: @NjitaArnaud: edit your original post with key information such as this

Comment: @NjitaArnaud Then in your store, just import `my router.js`. Also, in the future, include more info in your question, and it'll be easier to give you a proper answer.

Comment: I'm now facing another issue. At the level of checking if the response.status == 201 it should route to the desired page in .then block of my post request, it doesn't recognize the statement to be executed in the "if function" but in my console it prints out quite alright that the response status is 201, please do you have any idea of what could be the issue ???

Comment: Thanks for accepting :) In regards to your second question, couple of things to try: 1) Put a breakpoint inside the if block and confirm if it's reached. 2) Move the router block elsewhere and confirm that it works. If both parts work as expected, then when you put them together it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to load the router as a plugin.

In your store/index,js:

```
pinia.use(({ store }) => { store.router = markRaw(router) })
```

Then it will be accessible in your store modules like: `this.router.push`

Repeating the caveat that you must import YOUR router, such as from src/router (Quasar)